# Regular expression is not working for TestNg dependsOnMethods

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am trying to use Regular Expression for TestNg dependsOnMethods, but TestNg is not identifying the method. As I had gone through the TestNg documentation we can use Regular Expressions for dependsOnMethods and dependsOnGroups.

For Example, I have method like below,

```java
@Test
public void testParallel_1001(){
}
```

And I have another test method which depends on above method,

```java
@Test(dependsOnMethods = { "(.*?)1001" }, alwaysRun=true)
public void testParallel_1003(){

}
```

But it is not working for me.

I have also used, `/1001/` and `*.1001.*` but no luck. Please someone help me.

Comment: Is it just skipping that test method?

Comment: No it's doing nothing. i don't see any log in console.

Answer (score 0):

`dependsOnMethods` contains a list of exact method names, not regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

As per TestNG official [documentation](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html):
Both dependsOnGroups and dependsOnMethods accept regular expressions as parameters.

Comment: This answer would be better if you included a link to the part of the documentation where you found this information.

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation its soft dependency which accepts regular expression

http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#dependencies-with-annotations